# Como usar fadeIn() com um append()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Como adicionar o efeito de fadeIn(), junto com um append().

**[EXEMPLO](http://jsfiddle.net/7n2Fb/)**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Teste assim:

```
var count = 5; 
$('#addCount').click(function () {
    var p = $('<p>' + count + '</p>'); // criar o elemento 
    p.hide();                          // escondê-lo
    $('#new_elem').append(p);          // "appendê-lo" ou "appendar" o <p>
    p.fadeIn();                        // fazer fade in com ele já na página
    count++;
});
```

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/3XJdY/)

Comment: Boa! Isso mesmo, obrigado!

Comment: @JeffersonAlison, fico contente de ajudar :)